# woocommerce reorder tabs create php errors

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, tabs

I was using original snippet to reorders tabs.
then realized that if I forget to put description or attributes, these tabs are empty.
Then snippet creates php error.
here is the original code and my error comment. https://gist.github.com/woogists/abb8a37f8c708d712e46ce2d02ffdc43#file-wc-reorder-tabs-php

```
    add_filter( 'woocommerce_product_tabs', 'woo_reorder_tabs', 98 );
function woo_reorder_tabs( $tabs ) {
    if ($tabs[''] !== undefined)
    {
        $tabs['additional_information']['priority'] = 1;
    }
    return $tabs;
}
```

then I added if empty rule and changed the code like this. but this is also create another error.

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_product_tabs', 'woo_reorder_tabs', 98 );
function woo_reorder_tabs( $tabs ) {
    if ($tabs[''] !== undefined)
    {
        $tabs['additional_information']['priority'] = 1;
    }
    return $tabs;
}
```

here is the error

```
PHP Warning: Use of undefined constant undefined - assumed 'undefined' (this will throw an Error in a future version of PHP) in /kunder/gaming_10908/devgam_14130/public/wp-content/plugins/code-snippets/php/snippet-ops.php(469) : eval()'d code on line 6
```

Do you have any suggestion?

Answer (score 1):

PHP doesn't have the `undefined` constant. It is a javascript thing.

Your code should be as below.

```php
add_filter( 'woocommerce_product_tabs', 'woo_reorder_tabs', 98 );
function woo_reorder_tabs( $tabs ) {
    if ( is_array( $tabs ) )
    {
        $tabs['additional_information']['priority'] = 1;
    }
    return $tabs;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This one also worked for me.

```
    /**
 * Check if product has attributes, dimensions or weight to override the call_user_func() expects parameter 1 to be a valid callback error when changing the additional tab
 */
add_filter( 'woocommerce_product_tabs', 'woo_reorder_tabs', 98 );
function woo_reorder_tabs( $tabs ) {
    global $product;    
    $tabs['reviews']['priority'] = 40;
    if( $product->has_attributes() || $product->has_dimensions() || $product->has_weight() ) { // Check if product has attributes, dimensions or weight
        $tabs['additional_information']['priority'] = 3; 
    } 
    return $tabs; 
}`
```